# Cancan how to authorize collection model in one controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am using cancan with rails 4. My user model has many datings and a dating has many reply. In the user controller's show action, I want to authorize all of them:

```
@user = User.find params[:id]
authorize! :read, @user

@datings = @user.first_page_datings
authorize! :read, @datings

# How to authorize replies of all the datings here?
```

Question is how to authorize replies of all the datings here?

Comment: Can you try this `authorize! :read, Dating`

Comment: I think you are proposing authorize! :read, Reply? But this way, it cant tell which Reply to authorize. What I think now is loop dating and authorize dating's replies: @datings.each{|d|authorize! :read, d.replies}

Comment: try this `authorize! :read, @datings.replies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to authorize all the child objects, use `@dating = @user.datings.accessible_by(current_ability)` to load the permitted ones.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Consider this situation: In reply controller, I have index action. I get replies from: `@replies = @replyable.replies.accessible_by(current_ability)` In index template I also want to show user of each `@replies`: that is `@replies.first.user`. It's clear that `@replies.first.user` have not been authorized yet. Any thought?

Comment: In that case, I would test the ability in the view: `<%= reply.user if can?(:read, reply.user) %>`.